# InfluxDB 1.8 query help (show all values with same timestamp, and specific tag)

Tags: influxdb

i got following data structure:

[myImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSltM.png)

So each 12-16 min i send data to the influxDB with informations about several hosts.

I need to create a query, that counts all different “tag2” for each “tag1” (group by) and only for the last saved timestamp.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try following sample via [this doc](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/functions/#last)?

```
SELECT LAST(*) FROM "yourMeasurement" GROUP BY "tag1", "tag2";
```

Comment: Hello, but then i also get results from the timestamp before.